# Messed up my mouse config

Tags: mouse

I modified something in some config in May, then went to summer activities now I am back to my PC and I just found my mouse wheel behaves strangely. When I rotate it upwards everything is fine, it scrolls up, when I rotate it downwards it seems to be sending events for UP and for DOWN randomly and everything just randomly jumps on screen instead of scrolling in one direction.

This behavior is the same for xterm, firefox, gnome programs, geany, mplayerc. For mplayerc and other players music/video scrolls randomly back and forth.

So again, only rotate-wheel-dowm is broken, rotate-wheel-up is working perfectly.

I tried to connect different mouses from various vendors, both USB and wireless, they all behave the same weird way so it is not a mouse hardware failure, neither it is an `xinput` setting for a particular device I believe because they are set per a specific hardware mouse, isn't it? The same mouses work fine when connected to my smart tv so mouses are OK as devices.

Back in spring I was trying to make my Linux behave as if it had **mouseimp** Windows program installed, or like firefox extension drag-is-scroll, or more modern ScrollAnywhere for Firefox, to be precise I wanted this effect system wide when you press a mouse button and move the mouse something scrolls. I failed to achieve this but messed up my mouse instead. I do not remember what exact configs I touched because it was months ago, I remember googling for hours and trying random things, they did not enable drag-is-scroll behavior and at the time it seemed they caused no effect at all, now it's obvious my attempts broke my mouse behavior, and now it is too late I cannot remember what exactly I did so I cannot undo it. I remember sudo editing of files, trying something from github, clicking various buttons in the gnome preferences application maybe something else.

Any advice how to fix this problem?

I am already thinking about reinstalling my Ubuntu because it this, this is something I would like to avoid of course.

My system is AMD based PC with Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: some things to check ... maybe your text editor remembers a list of last few files edited ... check update timestamps of all files in /etc ... look at files that changed in may

Comment: the behavior sounds like a misconfigured hotkey ... the wheel-down could be performing multiple actions